# How to build javascript string so vbScript Split will split it back apart into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, vbscript

Do I need Carriage Returns (not familiar with it)? Currently this is how my JavaScript string is being built:

```
allcars = cars + makes;
```

Unfortunately, when I get to my Split function call (that I rather should not change), it does not split my JavaString back apart into an array:

```
CarsList = Split(Request("allcars"),vbCrLf)
```

When the Split function call gets string coming from a different source, it splits such string correctly (unlike with string from my JavaScript function).

Comment: What is the content of `cars`? What is the content of `makes`? What result do you expect after the split? Please provide examples.

Comment: cars and makes are simple strings of characters. I expect them form an array after split. and I do not want to insert any splitter symbols. Wiktor's solutions fulfills my needs.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't work without inserting a delimiter. If you use CR-LF as that delimiter or some other character (or character sequence) doesn't matter, as long as this character or character sequence doesn't appear elsewhere in your strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vbCrLf` constant represents a sequence of CR (carriage return, `\r`) and LF (line feed, `\n`) symbols. So, use

```
allcars = cars + "\r\n" + makes;
```